# OleDbConnection.Close() does not work

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbconnection

I have a method where I insert some data in a local MDB-Acces file. With this code it works fine:

```
try
{
   foreach (DataRow rowS99 in dtS99.Rows)
   {
      con.Open();
      da.InsertCommand = con.CreateCommand();
      da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wertListName", rowS99["WertListName"]);
      da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", rowS99["Key"]);
      da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bezeichner", rowS99["Bezeichner"]);
      da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keyAufbereitet", rowS99["KeyAufbereitet"]);
      da.InsertCommand.CommandText = sql;
      da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con.Close();
   }
   check = true;
}
```

When i put the Open and Close method outside the foreach loop the code works, but the local file, which was used with the connection, is already opened with Visual Studio so that i can't delete or move it. The Status of the connection says after `con.Close()` that it is closed.

What is the problem here?

Comment: It is better to move the open & close of the connection outside the foreach loop.  Otherwise, you'll open / close the connection multiple times which is not needed in this case.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels: or better, use `using` for `IDisposable`s.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels: Thats what i tried, but then the file is already in use through vshost32.exe and I can't delete or move the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have the Connection Opened and Closed within the loop. If there are 500 rows in your table then you will be opening & closing the connection 500 times, its not best practice..

Your connection should open in the Try statement before the loop and close once all Rows have been processed.

I think you would be best using the Update() function rather than the method your doing above.

You can take out the need to loop through each and every row.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx

Using this functionality allows you to add, edit and delete rows simply by calling the Update() method. You will need all 3 Commands setting up, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thtats what I tried, to put the open and close statement outside the loop, but then the file is always used from Visual Studio so that i can't delete or move it.

Comment: Then there is certainly a bug somewhere else. You need to run this in debug mode, and test it with just a simple 10 rows for example.. and look at what the debugger is doing step by step.

Comment: the loop runs more then 3000 times, but if it only runs 10 times it works

Comment: See my Edited Answer. You need to look at The DataApapter.Update() function. That way there is no need to loop through each row.

Comment: Sorry can you help me a little bit how i have to use the update function to write my datatable to my acces db.

Comment: Theres not much else you need to do, You already have your INSERT COmmand and DataAdapter. Just assign the InsertCOmmand as teh Insert command for your DataAdapter, and when you want to save changes back to the DataGrid, open a connection, call DataAdpater.UPdate(DataTable). This will then run the Insert Command on your Adapter and save changes to teh dataBase. Look at the link i   posted in my update.

Comment: Okay I have the solution: `da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
                OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
                da.Update(dtS99);` 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`IDbConnection.Close` method by default just returns connection back to the connection pool. It doesn't close the physical connection (either network connection or file). You may disable connection pooling (but this will decrease productivity of your application), or clear connection pool (see [`OleDbConnection.ReleaseObjectPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.releaseobjectpool.aspx)).

Comment: Tried this one out, but it doesn't fix my problem. That's really crazy, i don't know what the problem is...

Comment: @proud: have you read remarks section for `ReleaseObjectPool`? There's sequence description.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `con.close` in `finally()`.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help me. Again the same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
 con.Open();
 foreach (DataRow rowS99 in dtS99.Rows)
 {
  da.InsertCommand = con.CreateCommand();
  da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wertListName", rowS99["WertListName"]);
  da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", rowS99["Key"]);
  da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bezeichner", rowS99["Bezeichner"]);
  da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keyAufbereitet", rowS99["KeyAufbereitet"]);
  da.InsertCommand.CommandText = sql;
  da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
 con.Close();
 check = true;
 OleDb.OleDbConnection.ReleaseObjectPool();
 GC.Collect();  // I know attation
}
```

Works for me

Comment: A few words explaining why it works would be helpful.